# Create a protocol based style factory

Tags: swift

## Background

I have an app which interacts with a series of hardware devices.  These devices all have some base line functionality, but they can also have 0 or more "capabilities" (beyond their basic functionality).

Right now, there are something like 30+ "other" capabilities these devices "might" have

Further, to complicate the issue, the implementation of the capabilities on one device isn't the same on a different device (the world just doesn't work that way )

## The problem

I'm trying to design a API solution which will allow me to more easily manage this diverse range of functionality.

My initial attempt was to create a `protocol` for each capability and then conform each implementation of the device to these `protocol`s.

Needless to say, this is a mess.  As many of the capabilities aren't known until runtime and I'd need to create a class for each possible combination of capabilities, which isn't workable.

Also, in order for the App to determine if the device has a capability, I need to use `if instance is capable` and `if let capability = instance as? Capability`, every where, which isn't always pretty or always practical.

Some capabilities are mutable and the above just causes no end of compiler warnings.

There are other short comings as well, which require me to compromise the design, for example, to reduce the number of actual classes, I've had to put in "does support" options on many of the capabilities, as the instance of a device "might" support the capability, but isn't know until I interragate the device at runtime.

## "A" solution

I then thought, what I'd really like to do, is isolate the functionality of the capabilities into their own entities, seperate from the baseline devices themselves, so I can "ask" the device for an instance of the capability, and if it was capable of supporting it, it would return an instance, otherwise, it would return `nil`

Something like:

```
if let capability = device.capability(for: Capabilities.toggableSetting) {...}
```

The desire would be to use an `enum` to represent the supported capabilities, as this becomes self documenting, self validating, is readable and easily understood.

To that end, I came up with a really quick idea that looked something like

```
protocol Capability { }

protocol ToggableSetting: Capability {
    func set(value: String) //{}
}

enum Capabilities {
    case toggableSetting
}

protocol Device {
    func capability<T: Capability>(for capability: Capabilities) -> T?
}

class SomeImplementationOfToggableSetting: ToggableSetting {
    func set(value: String) {
        // NOOP
    }
}

class SomeDevice: Device {

    let toggableSetting = SomeImplementationOfToggableSetting()

    func capability<T>(for capability: Capabilities) -> T? where T : Capability {
        switch capability {
        case .toggableSetting: return toggableSetting as? T
        }
        return nil
    }

}

let test = SomeDevice()
let ts: ToggableSetting? = test.capability(for: .toggableSetting)
ts
```

As some of you will immediately see, this won't work, as it results in

> Protocol type 'ToggableSetting' cannot conform to 'Capability' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

at `let ts: ToggableSetting? = test.capability(for: .toggableSetting)`

So, after some reading and research, I then came up with the idea of introducing a "base" class...

```
class AnyToggableSetting: ToggableSetting {
    func set(value: String) { fatalError("Not yet implemented") }
}
```

Which needs to be implemented...

```
class SomeImplementationOfToggableSetting: AnyToggableSetting {
    override func set(value: String) {
        // NOOP
    }
}
```

And then I could use it something like...

```
let ts: AnyToggableSetting? = test.capability(for: .toggableSetting)
```

Okay, this works, but it's not as clean as I'd like.

I'd like to decouple the implementation and work to the `protocol` as much as possible, so my code says, "I want something that confirms too said `protocol`" and "not something that MUST extend from `AnySomething`"

There are other issues with the design I'd like to avoid if possible (properties don't inherit well for example)

## The "Question"

So, the basic question is, is there a way I can utilities this style of "factory" so that I can end up with the `protocol` over the need to supplying a `Any` style stand in object?